# CloudRun is going over max instance count (of 1)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run service (receiving no traffic) where I set the max instances and min instances to 1 so that it's always running.

When deploying a new instance, the instance count jumps to 3. This is a problem (I make some requests on instance start that hits a 429 if two instances are simultaneously making these requests).

**Why is CloudRun instance count going over my max?**

I can confirm my settings are correct and looking at the logs there are two new instances that start up.

PS: Cloudrun does have this message, which makes me think what I'm trying to do isn't possible. I just figured it would be because of downtime instead of extra instances.

> Revisions using a maximum number of instances of 3 or less might experience unexpected downtime.

Comment: Just for information , after your experience it's ok to set max instance to 1 ? Have you noticed any problems ?

Comment: @John I haven't had issues setting it to 1 any longer. On occasion, cloudrun WILL spike up instances. I find google cloud run to be buggy with their load balancing set up in their backend. So if going over 1 from time to time is an absolute NO, I wouldn't recommend it. for me, it wasn't an issue with very rare spikes (emphasizing very rare, like maybe once every other week? if I had to guess).

Comment: @John another note, it will increase instance counts from time to time, but the other is almost always idle, so nothing to worry about. Even when deploying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scenario seems to fit one described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#deploy), in which a new deployment for a Cloud Run service might temporarily create additional instances:

> When you deploy a new revision, Cloud Run gradually migrates traffic from the old revision to the new one. Because maximum instance limits are set for each revision, you may temporarily exceed the specified limit during the period after deployment.

Additional instances might be created to handle traffic migration from the previous revision to a new one. Cloud Run offers [settings](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#send-to-latest) that can alter how migration occurs between revisions. One of these settings is used to instantly serve all new traffic on the new revision. You can test if using this setting helps reduce the number of instances that are created. I tested one of the provided sample services and created multiple revisions, which did not exceed 1 active instance.

Comment: Thank you, I'm suprised that you tested it and it didn't exceed 1 active instance. It seems to do it to mine, even intermittently when it's sitting idle and I send an initial request. The only caveat is that every hour I send a call to get the latest data for my container which includes about 60 API calls.

Answer (score 1):

I read that it is a cloud run problem you need 10 instances and then the error disappears.

I understood that it is a bug in golang that does not know how to do it with two instances, but with 10 instances it should be fixed.

https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq/issues/54

Comment: Please update your answer with a reference link.

Comment: Thanks for the info Sergi, not sure if this answer's why as much as it shows that this is an actual issue. However, I noted that I had 0 requests incoming, unlike the comments in that thread